# Does ksh93 support +o type options with its getopts(1) builtin?

Tags: ksh

ksh93 supports long options the same way as introduced by Sun Microsystems in Spring 2004 for `getopt(3)`, `Bourne Shell` and `ksh88`.

You may e.g. use:

```
getopt(argc, argv, "V(version)");
```

to establish a long `--version` alias to the short option `-V`.

However `ksh93` does not use the `getopt(3)` from Solaris libc but an own implementation that internally is used to support short options that start with a `+` sign.

Is there a way to use this feature with the `ksh93` builtin `getopts(1)`implementation and iff, how does it work?

Comment: Try `getopts --man 2>&1 | more` in ksh93 for details.

Comment: I discovered this some time ago already, I however have been unable to understand it since there are no examples and the ksh concept seems to complex as it includes support for `--help` IIRC. Do you know examples for this `+o` feature?

Comment: Yes, by brain is not tuned to parse that man page either. There are plenty of examples in the ast-open source code though.

Answer (score 0):

That was an example of getopts usage I've tried

```
    #!/bin/ksh

    #Default value
    ONE=123
    TWO=456


    # getopts configuration
    USAGE="[-author?Andre Gelinas <andre.gelinas@foo.bar>]"
    USAGE+="[-copyright?2018]"
    USAGE+="[+NAME?TestGetOpts.sh]"
    USAGE+="[+DESCRIPTION?Try out for GetOps]"
    USAGE+="[o:one]#[one:=$ONE?First.]"
    USAGE+="[s:second]#[second:=$TWO?Second.]"
    USAGE+="[t:three]:[three?Third.]"
    USAGE+=$'[+SEE ALSO?\aman\a(1), \aGetOpts\a(1)]'

    while getopts "$USAGE" optchar ; do
        case $optchar in
                    o)  ONE=$OPTARG ;;
                    s)  TWO=$OPTARG ;;
                    t)  THREE=$OPTARG ;;
        esac
    done

    print "ONE = "$ONE
    print "TWO = "$TWO
    print "THREE = "$THREE
```

You can use either --one or -o. Using --man or --help are also working. Also -o and -s are numeric only, but -t will take anything. By the way, you might want to look at https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/korn/appb_11.htm also.